# How to make batch requests using LinkedIn API?

Tags: curl, linkedin-api

I started to work with the LinkedIn API, trying to the social metadata (#reactions, #comments) for shares. I get it to work using the endpoint to get the metadata for individual shares. So I'm pretty sure that my access token and everything works.

However, I can't seem to get it to work with the endpoint to make batch requests. When I try:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialMetadata?ids=List(urn:li:activity:XXX,urn:li:activity:XXX)' \
     -H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \ 
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXX
```

I get the error

> {"status":400,"code":"VERSION_MISSING","message":"A version must be present. Please specify a version by adding the LinkedIn-Version header."}

Well, fair enough, although it's not used in the cURL example in the docs. However, if I add the LinkedIn version:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialMetadata?ids=List(urn:li:activity:XXX,urn:li:activity:XXX)' \
     -H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \ 
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXX \
     -H 'LinkedIn-Version: 202401'
```

I now get the error:

> {"status":400,"code":"ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT","message":"Invalid query parameters passed to request"}

I'm sure I'm missing something simple/silly, but I just can spot the problem. It sounds like that the query parameter:

```
?ids=List(urn:li:activity:XXX,urn:li:activity:XXX)
```

is wrong; of course, I use value values instead of 'XXX', but that's just how I read it from the docs -- here's the examepl cURL command they show:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialMetadata?ids=List({shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn},{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn})' \
-H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}'
```